# Storing 3 different variables (dict. or list) while iterating through documents?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, text, dataframe

I am iterating through hundreds of thousands of words in several documents, looking to find the frequencies of contractions in English. I have formatted the documents appropriately, and it's now a matter of writing the correct function and storing the data properly. I need to store information for each document on which contractions were found and how frequently they were used in the document. Ideally, my data frame would look something like the following:

```
filename    contraction    count
file1       it's           34
file1       they're        13
file1       she's          9
file2       it's           14
file2       we're          15
file3       it's           4
file4       it's           45
file4       she's          13
```

How can I best go about this?

Edit: Here's my code, thus far:

```
for i in contractions_list:     # for each of the 144 contractions in my list
    for l in every_link:        # for each speech
        count = 0
        word_count = 0
        content_2 = processURL_short(l)
        for word in content2.split():
            word = word.strip(p)
            word_count = word_count + 1
            if i in contractions:
                count = count + 1
```

Where `processURL_short()` is a function I wrote that scrapes a website and returns a speech as `str`.

Edit2:

```
link_store = {}
for i in contractions_list_test:     # for each of the 144 contractions
    for l in every_link_test:        # for each speech
        link_store[l] = {}
        count = 0
        word_count = 0
        content_2 = processURL_short(l)
        for word in content_2.split():
            word = word.strip(p)
            word_count = word_count + 1
            if word == i:
                count = count + 1
        if count: link_store[l][i] = count
        print i,l,count
```

Here's my file-naming code:

```
splitlink = l.split("/")
president = splitlink[4]
speech_num = splitlink[-1]
filename = "{0}_{1}".format(president,speech_num)
```

Comment: How large is the total input stream?  Feeding a dictionary with a generator stream may be your best solution.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you mean by input stream correctly, there's a stream of 900 text files (all no longer than 25000 words, avg. about 10000), and 144 contractions in my dictionary

Comment: Right.  In that case, it's not worth changing your other code at this point.  If you do get larger files, consider learning how to write a Python generator (see the **yield** statement) and you can save on run-time memory without sacrificing much speed (usually within 10%, sometimes faster).

Answer (score 1):

Opening and reading are slow operations: don't cycle through the entire file list 144 times.

Exceptions are slow: throwing an exception for every non-contraction in every speech will be ponderous.

Don't cycle through your list of contractions checking against words.  Instead, use the built-in **in** function to see whether that contraction is on the list, and then use a dictionary to tally the entries, just as you might do by hand.

Go through the files, word by word.  When you see a word on the contraction list, see whether it's already on your tally sheet.  If so, add a mark, if not, add it to the sheet with a count of 1.

Here's an example.  I've made very short speeches and a trivial **processURL_short** function.

```
def processURL_short(string):
    return string.lower()

every_link = [
    "It's time for going to Sardi's",
    "We're in the mood; it's about DST",
    "They're he's it's don't",
    "I'll be home for Christmas"]

contraction_list = [
    "it's",
    "don't",
    "can't",
    "i'll",
    "he's",
    "she's",
    "they're"
]

for l in every_link:        # for each speech
    contraction_count = {}
    content = processURL_short(l)

    for word in content.split():
        if word in contraction_list:
            if word in contraction_count:
                contraction_count[word] += 1
            else:
                contraction_count[word] = 1

    for key, value in contraction_count.items():
        print key, '\t', value
```

Comment: Alright. That works really well, but I'd still like to be able to store each contraction along with each speech's `filename`, so that my dictionary looks like the table I put above.

Comment: Ah -- so we're counting contractions for each speech, not overall.  Fine.  Move **contraction_count = {}** just under the first **for** statement, and then put your code inside that loop as appropriate.

Comment: How do I get the `filename` linked up with the contractions found in each individual document? I'm going to iterate through 900 speeches (contained in `every_link`), and would like to pair filenames with contraction counts for each doc.

Comment: I pulled the reset and print statements inside the loop to handle this.  Add your code to handle the file name.  This includes inserting the file name into the print statement at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

you can have your structure set up like this:

```
links = {}

for l in every_link:
    links[l] = {}
    for i in contractions_list:
        count = 0
        ... #here is where you do your count, which you seem to know how to do
        ... #note that in your code, i think you meant if i in word/ if i == word for your final if statement
        if count: links[l][i] = count #only adds the value if count is not 0
```

you would end up with a data structure like this:

```
links = {
'file1':{
    "it's":34,
    "they're":14,
    ...,
    },
'file2':{
    ....,
    },
...,
}
```

which you could easily iterate through to write the necessary data to your file (which i again assume you know how to do since its seemingly not part of the question)

Comment: Please see the edit above. I think it would be better to, for each contraction, iterate through all of the documents. But, I'm getting an empty dictionary!

Comment: would you be able to print the values of `contractions_list_test,every_link_test, and content_2`? it may be something with those values

Comment: `contractions_list_test` looks like `["she'll", "shouldn't've", "she'll've", "don't", "somebody'll", "should've", "won't", "that'll", "who'll've", "he's", "when's", "we've", "somebody'd've", "he'd", "ma'am"]`, every_link_test looks like `['http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4427', 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4424', 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4453']`, and `content_2` is just a body of text like `"I am the President, and I don't want to go home. Don't go over there."` stuff like that

Comment: and you are getting a completely empty dictionary? is `link_store` empty or is `link_store[l]` empty? because regardless of whether anything is found, `link_store` should never be empty unless either `every_link_test` or `contractions_list_test` are empty

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries seems to be the best option here, because they will allow
you easier manipulation of your data.  Your goal should be indexing
results by filename extracted form the `link` (the URL to your speech
text) to a mapping of contraction and its count.

Something like:

```
{"file1": {"it's": 34, "they're": 13, "she's": 9},
 "file2": {"it's": 14, "we're": 15},
 "file3": {"it's": 4},
 "file4": {"it's": 45, "she's": 13}}
```

Here's the full code:

```py
ret = {}
for link, text in ((l, processURL_short(l)) for l in every_link):
    contractions = {c:0 for c in contractions_list}
    for word in text.split():
        try:
            contractions[word] += 1
        except KeyError:
            # Word or contraction not found.
            pass
    ret[file_naming_code(link)] = contractions
```

Let's go into each step.

1. First we intialize `ret`, it will be the resulting dictionary.  Then we use
   [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)
   to perform `processURL_short()` for each step (instead of going though
   all link list at once).  We return a list of tuple `(<link-name>, <speech-test>)` so we can use the link name later.
2. Next That's the contractions count mapping, intialize to `0`s, it
   will be used to count contractions.
3. Then we split the text into words, for each word we search for it
   in the contractions mapping, if found we count it, otherwise
   `KeyError` will be raise for each key not found.

   (Another question stated that this will perform poorly, another
   possiblity is checking with `in`, like `word in contractions`.)
4. Finally:

   ```
   ret[file_naming_code(link)] = contractions
   ```

   Now `ret` is a dictionary of filename mapping to contractions
   occurrences.  Now you can easily create your table using:

Here's how you would get your output:

```
print '\t'.join(('filename', 'contraction', 'count'))
for link, counts in ret.items():
    for name, count in counts.items():
        print '\t'.join((link, name, count))
```